# launchctl dumpstate won't give full dump

Tags: command-line, launchd

`launchctl dumpstate` is giving me exactly 20mb of data then just exits in the middle of a service description:

```
    inherited environment = {
        PATH => /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
        SSH_AUTH_SOCK => /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.O4qEwMxtXY/Listeners
        TM%

➜  ~ wc -c launchstate.txt
 20971520 launchstate.txt
```

Anyone know how to get the full dump?  `dumpstate` isn't documented in `man` and I can't find other documentation for it.